# Why is Object.GetType() a method instead of a property?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

From a design perspective, I wonder why the .NET creators chose System.Object.GetType() instead of a System.Object.Type read-only property.

Is it just a (very minor) design flaw or is there rationale behind there?
Any lights welcome.

Comment: +1 brilliant question. To summarize, 1) to be consistent as `GetType` can overloads (by Philippe), 2) since properties can't throw exceptions (by Mikko), 3) since properties can't be expensive (by Joel), 4) for performance reasons (by Martin). +1 for all of them.

Comment: @nawfal Properties can, and do throw exceptions. The example brought up was `Nullable<T>`. Interesting because calling the `Value` property throws an exception when `HasValue` is `false`.

Comment: @MrAnderson I sure worded it wrong. I mean properties preferably shouldn't throw exceptions, it is just a good practice, not a rule. Properties can and should throw if it makes sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at the GetType() declaration in Reflector you'll find this:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

What that combination of attribute and extern means is that this method is actually implemented in unmanaged code inside the .NET runtime itself. The GUID question in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163896.aspx) goes into further details. They obviously did this for performance reasons after determining that figuring out the Type would be faster if handled at a lower level.

This leads to two reasons not to implement the GetType method as a property. Firstly you can't define properties extern as you can with methods, so it would need to be handled in native .NET code. Secondly even if you could define them as extern, performing an unsafe, unmanaged call from inside a property would definitely break the guidelines for property usage since it's much harder to guarantee that there are no side effects.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Properties CAN be declared as extern. This is perfectly valid: `public extern Type Type { [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]get; }`

Answer (score 7):

The guidelines say that a property should represent a state of the object, it should not be expensive performance wise, and it should not have side effects apart from computing/setting that state. My guess is GetType() does not respect these rules so they made it a method.

GetType() is a slightly expensive operation. If it were a property it would encourage uses like

```
DoStuff(obj.Type);
....
DoStuff(obj.Type);
```

etc.

instead of

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
DoStuff(type);
....
DoStuff(type);
```

and that would be not so optimal. So they made it a method to suggest that it should be called sparingly.

Comment: On the other hand, it does represent the state of an object, because the type can't change over the lifetime of an object.

Comment: I would rather see the former code. Optimise for readability first. When you say it's "slightly expensive", how expensive are we really talking? On my NC10 netbook, 10 million calls to GetType() took about 200ms. That's significantly faster than a property which just synchronizes and then returns a private variable. (A trivial property is faster still, admittedly...) I don't think this is a good reason to make it a method.

Comment: mea culpa for not measuring first. but we need to keep in mind that the method is there from 1.0 and it could have been slower those days.
just my 2 cents. 
anyway - i've just been "skeeted" :). and that's a good thing

Comment: Jon Skeet, the time it takes for GetType to execute depends on how many loaded assemblies you have. I'm trying to optimize some code now and in my case, 8 calls take about 600ms which is a lot.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert It does represent a state of the object, but I'm wondering why do you say *it is because a property can't change*? Properties should represent state, but it can change. While I agree `Type` property doesn't change, I'm asking why are you making the very immutability a reason to state that Type property represents state of object.

Comment: @AZ. Yes properties should represent state, but how is a Type property like `obj.Type` violating that? As Philippe says it is indeed representing a state. No +1 for that statement.

Comment: @nawfal - pretty late to the party :). yes it represents state but my actual suggestion was about performance and considering Roman's comment it seems it does have an impact in some cases. Anyway the already accepted answer is the most relevant

Comment: @AZ. then remove the point on *state* from your answer, and make it more meaningful :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, if Jeffrey Richter's ["C# via CLR"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627048.do "Book page on O'Reilly") is anything to go by (and IMO it is), holding on to a `Type` object (here: by referencing it in a property's backing field) might not be such a terrific idea, since `Type` objects are fairly expensive (at least memory-wise). Perhaps a `WeakReference` to `Type` or using a `RuntimeTypeHandle` instead would be appropriate (even though both would again make the property computationally more expensive).

Comment: @stakx: I don't *think* that `Type` objects are ever garbage collected until the AppDomain is unloaded - so it would make no difference in those terms. Do you have any indication that types *are* garbage collected?

Comment: @JonSkeet: My above comment is only as accurate as Jeffrey Richter's knowledge of the CLR. From "C# via CLR", 3rd edition, p. 658: _"`Type` and `MemberInfo`-derived objects require a lot of memory. So if an application holds on to too many of these objects …, the application's memory consumption increases dramatically, having an adverse effect on the application's performance. Internally, the CLR has a more compact way of representing this information. The CLR creates these objects for our application only to make things easier for developers."_ (There's more, but let that suffice for now.)

Comment: @stakx: Worth investigating, I guess. I have noticed a few times where Richter can be a little alarmist around performance, mind you. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, it is in general considered good practice for internal fields or values which are trivial to calculate to be exposed using a property, and other values, which may require more time or other resources to calculate, to be exposed using a method.

Answer (score 3):

Only Microsoft can answer that question, but I think it's because several classes in the .NET Framework create their own overloaded versions of GetType() with extra parameters. If it would have been a property, they couldn't use the same name (because properties don't have parameters).

Just my thoughts on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late reply but crashed into the question while trying to find something related.

It is possible for GetType to throw an exception. Framework guidelines state that properties should not throw exceptions. This is one more reason why it should be a method instead of property.

Comment: Mikko, according to the docs, GetType() doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Calling `GetType()` on a `Nullable<T>` will throw an exception if the `HasValue` field is null.  That wasn't an issue when `GetType()` was invented (since `Nullable<T>` didn't exist then) but it would be odd behavior if `GetType` were a property (since a `Nullable<T>` is never really null, and has properties like `HasValue` which always work just fine).

Comment: supercat, I assume you meant Value might be null? HasValue is simply boolean, true or false, never null.

Comment: @ConcreteGannet: I meant whose `HasValue` field is false.  Neither field can be `null`.

Comment: @supercat The `Value` property throws an exception if `HasValue` is `false`. There is an example of a property throwing an exception.

Comment: @MrAnderson: The Framework guidelines say that things which can throw exceptions should be methods rather than properties; the behavior of `Nullable<T>.Value` violates that guideline.  My earlier comment was about `GetType()`.  The existence of a field or variable of type `Nullable<T>` does not depend upon whether its `HasValue` property yields `true` or `false`; the `ToString()` method is defined to work on such instances of `Nullable<T>`, but `GetType()` will throw an exception.

Comment: @supercat The exception is a `NullReferenceException`, behavior that is expected when calling an instance method or property on `null`. This happens in this case because `GetType()` always requires a box for a value type. And boxing a nullable type results in `null` if `HasValue` is `false`. `ToString()` does NOT always require box if the compiler knows an override exists, and `ToString()` is overridden in `Nullable<T>`. If you force a box by saying `object o = new int?(); o.ToString();`, then you will get same exception.

Comment: @MrAnderson: Is there any other instance where invoking an instance method on a variable of value type can yield a `NullReferenceException` without executing any code associated with that method?  Rather than defining a rule which is only applicable to one method and saying that the behavior is a consequence of the "rule" rather than the method, I would think it more helpful to associate the behavior with the method.

Comment: @supercat I agree with you. Personally, I would advocate for `GetType()` to return `typeof(Nullable<int>)` when called directly on an unboxed `Nullable<int>` variable, but I don't make the rules ;)

Comment: @MrAnderson: From what I've read, the decision to make default-valued `Nullable<T>` box as `null` was made relatively late, and I don't think people thought it through fully.  Otherwise, I think of `GetType` as being a method whose purpose is to retrieve information from an object's header.  Value-type objects get boxed not because `GetType` isn't a virtual method, but rather because an unboxed instance won't have a header that `GetType` could retrieve.

Comment: @supercat IMO, the compiler should just emit `ldtoken` every time `GetType()` is called on a known value type to avoid boxing. Or at least give a warning, something like `Please use typeof(int) instead of 1.GetType()`

Comment: @MrAnderson: If a generic function calls `GetType` on a non-null non-empty instance of `T`, the type that's returned will be `T` unless `T` was of the form `Nullable<U>` in which case it will return `U`.